# What is the difference between `>>> some_object` and `>>> print some_object` in the Python interpreter?

Tags: printing, behavior, python

In the interpreter you can just write the name of an object e.g. a list `a = [1, 2, 3, u"hellö"]` at the interpreter prompt like this:

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, u'hell\xf6']
```

or you can do:

```
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, u'hell\xf6']
```

which seems equivalent for lists. At the moment I am working with hdf5 to manage some data and I realized that there is a difference between the two methods mentioned above. Given:

```
with tables.openFile("tutorial.h5", mode = "w", title = "Some Title") as h5file:
    group = h5file.createGroup("/", 'node', 'Node information')
    tables.table = h5file.createTable(group, 'readout', Node, "Readout example")
```

The output of

```
print h5file
```

differs from

```
>>> h5file
```

So I was wondering if someone could explain Python's behavioral differences in these two cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typing an object into the terminal calls `__repr__()`, which is for a detailed representation of the object you are printing (unambiguous).  When you tell something to 'print', you are calling `__str__()` and therefore asking for something human readable.

Alex Martelli gave a great explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python/1436756#1436756).  Other responses in the thread might also illuminate the difference.

For example, take a look at datetime objects.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Compare...

```
>>> now
Out: datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 18, 15, 10, 29, 827606)
```

to...

```
>>> print now
Out: 2011-08-18 15:10:29.827606
```

Hopefully that makes it a little more clear!

Comment: For a None variable, typing the variable doesn't print anything. Yet `print(repr(None))` gives `None`. How come?

Answer (score 2):

The interactive interpreter will print the result of each expression typed into it.  (Since statements do not evaluate, but rather execute, this printing behavior does not apply to statements such as `print` itself, loops, etc.)

Proof that `repr()` is used by the interactive interpreter as stated by Niklas Rosenstein (using a 2.6 interpreter):

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return 'repr Foo'
...   def __str__(self):
...     return 'str Foo'
...
>>> x = Foo()
>>> x
repr Foo
>>> print x
str Foo
```

So while the `print` statement may be unnecessary in the interactive interpreter (unless you need `str` and not `repr`), the non-interactive interpreter does not do this.  Placing the above code in a file and running the file will result in nothing being printed.

Comment: Yes, x will be printed, because there is a print statement ;)

Comment: Ha, that's funny.  I edited the answer to include the `print x` statement to show that one uses `str` and the other `repr` and forgot to amend the final paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The print statement always calls `x.__str__()` method while (only in the interactive interpeter) simply calling a variable the objects `x.__repr__()` method ia called.

```
>>> '\x02agh'
'\x02agh'
>>> print '\x02agh'
'agh'
```

Comment: Where is this documented? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @jtbandes Don't know where, but you can test it yourself. PS: Can somebody pleaso format the inline codes right ? It doesnt work on a mobile device. Thanks !

Comment: Haha, i really dunno where, but for sure somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: You mean `str(x)` and `repr(x)`, not `x.str()` and `x.repr()`.

Comment: or `x.__str__()` and `x.__repr__()`

Comment: It was just a formatting problem, he couldn't enter backticks on his mobile device (as he said). I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Python documentation at: [http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](http://object.__repr__%28self%29%20%20%20%20%20%20Called%20by%20the%20repr%28%29%20built-in%20function%20and%20by%20string%20conversions%20%28reverse%20quotes%29%20to%20compute%20the%20%E2%80%9Cofficial%E2%80%9D%20string%20representation%20of%20an%20object.%20If%20at%20all%20possible,%20this%20should%20look%20like%20a%20valid%20Python%20expression%20that%20could%20be%20used%20to%20recreate%20an%20object%20with%20the%20same%20value%20%28given%20an%20appropriate%20environment%29.%20If%20this%20is%20not%20possible,%20a%20string%20of%20the%20form%20%3C...some%20useful%20description...%3E%20should%20be%20returned.%20The%20return%20value%20must%20be%20a%20string%20object.%20If%20a%20class%20defines%20__repr__%28%29%20but%20not%20__str__%28%29,%20then%20__repr__%28%29%20is%20also%20used%20when%20an%20%E2%80%9Cinformal%E2%80%9D%20string%20representation%20of%20instances%20of%20that%20class%20is%20required.%20%20%20%20%20%20This%20is%20typically%20used%20for%20debugging,%20so%20it%20is%20important%20that%20the%20representation%20is%20information-rich%20and%20unambiguous.%20%20object.__str__%28self%29%20%20%20%20%20%20Called%20by%20the%20str%28%29%20built-in%20function%20and%20by%20the%20print%20statement%20to%20compute%20the%20%E2%80%9Cinformal%E2%80%9D%20string%20representation%20of%20an%20object.%20This%20differs%20from%20__repr__%28%29%20in%20that%20it%20does%20not%20have%20to%20be%20a%20valid%20Python%20expression%3a%20a%20more%20convenient%20or%20concise%20representation%20may%20be%20used%20instead.%20The%20return%20value%20must%20be%20a%20string%20object.)

> object.**repr**(self)
>
> ```
> Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions
> ```
>
> (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an
>   object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python
>   expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same
>   value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a
>   string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned.
>   The return value must be a string object. If a class defines
>   **repr**() but not **str**(), then **repr**() is also used when an
>   “informal” string representation of instances of that class is
>   required.
>
> ```
> This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the
> ```
>
> representation is information-rich and unambiguous.
>
> object.**str**(self)
>
> ```
> Called by the str() built-in function and by the print statement
> ```
>
> to compute the “informal” string representation of an object. This
>   differs from **repr**() in that it does not have to be a valid Python
>   expression: a more convenient or concise representation may be used
>   instead. The return value must be a string object.

Example:

```
>>> class A():
...    def __repr__(self): return "repr!"
...    def __str__(self): return "str!"
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a
repr!
>>> print(a)
str!
>>> class B():
...    def __repr__(self): return "repr!"
... 
>>> class C():
...    def __str__(self): return "str!"
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b
repr!
>>> print(b)
repr!
>>> c = C()
>>> c
<__main__.C object at 0x7f7162efb590>
>>> print(c)
str!
```

Print function prints the console every arguments `__str__`. Like `print(str(obj))`.

But in interactive console, it print function's return value's `__repr__`. And if `__str__` not defined, `__repr__` could be used instead.

Ideally, `__repr__` means, we should just use that representation to reproduce that object. It shouldn't be identical between different classes, or object's that represents different values, For example, datetime.time:

But `__str__` (what we get from `str(obj)`) should seem nice, because we show it to user.

```
>>> a = datetime.time(16, 42, 3)
>>> repr(a)
'datetime.time(16, 42, 3)'
>>> str(a)
'16:42:03' #We dont know what it is could be just print:
>>> print("'16:42:03'")
'16:42:03'
```

And, sorry for bad English :).

Answer (score 0):

`print(variable)` equals to `print(str(variable))`

whereas

`variable` equals to `print(repr(variable))`

Obviously, the `__repr__` and `__str__` method of the object `h5file` produce different results.